# AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

Here is a sample code I was running for opencv

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

img = cv2.imread('rose.png')
print("Image Properties")
print(" - Number of Pixels:" + str(img.size))
print("-Shape/Dimensions:" + str(img.shape))

blue, green, red = cv2.split(img) # Split the image into its channels
img_gs = cv2.imread('rose.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) # Convert image to grayscale
cv2_imshow(img_gs)
```

Below is the error Im getting. I have tried other solutions suggesting issue with pillow version etc. But somehow this doesn't work.

```
cv2_imshow(img_gs)
  File "/Users/fazalshaik/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/colab/patches/__init__.py", line 29, in cv2_imshow
    display.display(PIL.Image.fromarray(a))
AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'
```

Comment: hmm, it seems the problem is in Google's `cv2_imshow` function. Try reporting it as an issue to them.

Comment: Try adding a line near the top `from PIL import Image`

Comment: Adding it throws new error UserWarning: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.
  warn("IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.")
/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:726: UserWarning: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
  warn("Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please "
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=786x1180 at 0x10AF5A240>

Comment: @Marko any idea where to report the issue?

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/master/google/colab/patches/__init__.py) you can see the code which is failing, and [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues) you can report an issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.  Are you running this on Google Colab?  The path to the file that is producing this error suggests that you are running this locally.  This workaround for `cv2_imshow` is specifically for running on Colab.